# Selecting Two Columns and creating a chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Hi I am pretty new to VBA. I am trying to create a chart with values from Two columns A1:A10, C1:C10 (i.e. A and C).I selected these two columns with mouse and when i try the macro code i am getting the following error " Run-time error 1004, Application error or Object defined error". But i am able to create chart when i select columns A and B (i.e. A1:B10). Need some suggestion.

This is my code:

```
Sub Chart()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A10,C1:C10")
        .Shapes.AddChart
        Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.count)
        Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Or if you still want to use `.Selection` then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Selection.Parent.Name)
    With ws
        Set rng = Selection
        .Shapes.AddChart
        Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.count)
        Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```